# Set 24 hours remaining countdown

Tags: javascript, jquery

Okay as you can probably tell from the title of this post. I'm trying to work how to create a 24 hour remaining count down clock. I just can't get my head around how to work this out.

I've got it working with 5 minutes, but I just need a nudge in the right direction on how to turn this into hours instead of

[JSFiddle Demo](http://jsfiddle.net/mjngwzw2/4/)

HTML:

```
<body>
    <input type="text" value="5">
    <div>Time Remaining <span id="remainingTime">05:00</span> minutes!</div>
</body>
```

JavaScript/jQuery:

```
function Timer(duration, display) 
{
    var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;
    setInterval(function () {
        minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10)
        seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

        display.text(minutes + ":" + seconds);

        if (--timer < 0) {
            timer = duration;
        }
    }, 1000);
}

jQuery(function ($) 
{
    var fiveMinutes = 60 * jQuery('#checkTime').val();
    var display = $('#remainingTime');
    Timer(fiveMinutes, display);
});
```

No plugins please.

Comment: This has been said a thousand times before I know, but why not use a simple jQuery plugin for this? Especially since you are already loading jQuery as a dependency. Or is this a pet project to learn how to build a timer?

Comment: @JonKoops - This is a pet project and I don't want to use jQuery plugin

Comment: @JonKoops I am probably being stupid with this and the answer being 60 * 60 * whatever number is in the input field?

Comment: Not really, though for debugging purposes I'd recommend using a set number until the rest of the logic is functional.

Comment: Note that the first line in your `Timer` function is not correct (`var timer = duration, minutes, seconds;`). You can't assign and create new variables at the same time. Also since the `minutes` and `seconds` variables are only used inside the anonymous function you should define them there.

Comment: @JonKoops can you explain what you mean with your 2nd phrase? I believe there's nothing wrong with the variable creation/assignment here.

Comment: @Joum It's basically what I said before. The variables are only used within the setInterval so they should be declared there as well.

Comment: The assignment is valid though, but the value will be `undefined`. Just looks hard to read.

Comment: @JonKoops undefined but just until it's updated at the beginning of the callback, so no problem! :P

Comment: Still, makes more sense to keep it in scope where it belongs. Might cause state to leak where it shouldn't when more code is added in the future.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

I changed your fiddle a bit,

```
function Timer(duration, display) 
{
    var timer = duration, hours, minutes, seconds;
    setInterval(function () {
        hours = parseInt((timer /3600)%24, 10)
        minutes = parseInt((timer / 60)%60, 10)
        seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);

        hours = hours < 10 ? "0" + hours : hours;
        minutes = minutes < 10 ? "0" + minutes : minutes;
        seconds = seconds < 10 ? "0" + seconds : seconds;

        display.text(hours +":"+minutes + ":" + seconds);

                --timer;
    }, 1000);
}

jQuery(function ($) 
{
    var twentyFourHours = 24 * 60 * 60;
    var display = $('#remainingTime');
    Timer(twentyFourHours, display);
});
```

Check it out here: http://jsfiddle.net/j1zn0x9c/

EDIT: Mind the corrections I made. This isn't at all linear. Check [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/1322830/24098), too.

Comment: @ChrisBeckett ... fixed it, sorry for the stoopid bugs. :D

Answer (score 0):

You can use this small javascript project: http://neswork.com/javascript/alarm-clock/ Either directly or to copy the functionality you want

Answer (score 0):

Just doing inside a `setTimeout` will slip the timer eventually .

Better to do something like shown below

```
function timerUpdate() {        
    var currentTime = new Date();
    var h = currentTime.getHours();
    var m = currentTime.getMinutes();
    var s = currentTime.getSeconds();

    setTimeout(timerUpdate,1000);

    //Update the hour, minute and second in UI
}
```

what i mean is, sync your countdown frequently.
also the 1 second timer can be improved using 2 timer or with a bigger delay

Answer (score 0):

You should do your homework. So, I will just give you an idea how to modify this.

1. Your `fiveMinutes` variable provides the time in seconds. If the value of `#checkTime` is 5 then `fiveMinutes` is equal to 300. If you need 24 hours, this variable should be `60 x 60 x 24`.
2. Now when this number of seconds is passed inside the function, it breaks the number down to minutes and seconds.

   ```
   minutes = parseInt(timer / 60, 10);    //n secs div 60 = minutes   
   seconds = parseInt(timer % 60, 10);
   ```

   You need to add hours to this.

   ```
   hours = parseInt(timer / 60 * 60)      // (n secs div 60 = mins) div 60 = hours
   ```
3. Modify your `display` string to show hours too.

Please do your homework now.

Comment: Not mean to be a drag, but the sanctimonious "do your homework" bits are a bit uncalled for. Specially when you don't even shed that much light over his issue.

Comment: I shed more light than you. My light even covered the aspect of his voluntary understanding of code than seeking  full solution from outside.

Comment: K dude... have a nice one!

Answer (score 0):

can you use moment.js? It can save you a lot of complexity when working with times in your code. [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/adrian_r/7wkcn3sz/1/)

code:

```
    function Timer(duration, display) 
{
   var myInterval = setInterval(function () {
        var subtract = duration.subtract(1, 'seconds');
        var formatted = moment(subtract).format('HH:mm:ss');
        if(formatted === '00:00:00'){
            clearInterval(myInterval);
        }
        display.text(formatted);

    }, 1000);
}

jQuery(function ($) 
{
    var fiveMinutes = moment().hours(23).minutes(59).seconds(59);
    var display = $('#remainingTime');
    Timer(fiveMinutes, display);
});
```

Comment: just saw your no plugins please addition... so nevermind.